# Read spatial point type with an api-platform graphql query

Tags: postgresql, graphql, spatial, api-platform.com

Here is my stack:

- postgres 12
- GraphQL with api platform

I have an entity with a coordinates attribute based on point Type from the package longitude-one/doctrine-spatial, and I would like to access to this attribute through a graphQL request, but graphQL ignore this attribute as it doesn't recognize the type...
How can I make it return my attribute, I tried through a customType but I don't want to loose postgres benefits with the geometryViewer ...
Does anyone know how to handle this ? Or did it with a different type ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, when you use graphQL with api platform, and when you create a new attribute to the entity through the symfony cli, the getters and the setters are automatically created.

For example:

> If I create a new entity called NewEntity. I will have a setNewEntity
> method and a getNewEntity method, that are based on the type the
> entity have.

The get method is important has it will be used by api platform to return the data in your graphql response. And this is where you can format the data the way you want.

In my geometry example, I will have:

```
#[ORM\Column(type: "point")]
private $myCoordinates;

public function getMyCoordinates(): ?array
{
    if ($this->myCoordinates) {
        return [
            "longitude" => $this->myCoordinates->getLongitude(),
            "latitude" => $this->myCoordinates->getLatitude()
        ];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```